# Disable flutter TextField cursor/carret from blinking so it always stays visible

Tags: flutter

In flutter, I am making my own keyboard to use with `TextField`s. When I am typing using that keyboard, the cursor always blinks as if I am not typing. *I want to mimic the behavior when you type so it always stays visible, and when I am not doing anything - the cursor keeps blinking.*

**Basicaly, I want the ability to control if the cursor is blinking or always stays visible.** Or if you know any other workaround, I am more than open to suggestions.